# Where can I find formulas or calculators for apparent moon sizes?

Tags: moons, astronomy, worldbuilding-resources

(New here!)
As I am setting up the astronomic framework of my new world, I have real issues finding information, formulas and calculators to get the actual size (diameter or radius) or apparent size (disk size) of my moons.

I know my roche limit and the hill sphere of my planet, and I have 3 placed moons in given distances from my planet and their orbital period, but how do I go on with actual size and apparent size of a moon? Doesn't that depend on mass too?
I need to know how big my moons must be, for example so that one of them covers the sun disk for an eclipse with a corona, and for other reasons.

**Any known links to calculators or formulas regarding this topic?**

For completion, these are my moon datas at the moment, the planet is roughly like earth (1 earth mass, 0.9 radius):

Moon 1 - distance: 19.110 km, orbital period: 7.27 hours

Moon 2 - distance: 171.990 km, orbital period: 196.4 hours

Moon 3 - distance: 509.000 km, orbital period: 1001.76 hours

Comment: Welcome to the site. Would your question not better be asked at astronomy.se ?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding SE and Stack Exchange. Useful terminology: *angle subtended*.

Comment: @Burki thanks for the hint, I will use that place to let my system be "proofread" once I have collected the most data.

Comment: @Polarelch Just so you know, Astronomy.SE and Physics.SE and the other hard sciences usually close questions about speculative or fictional systems. If you want your system to be proof-read, posting here at Worldbuilding with the reality check tag is best.

Comment: @kingledion thanks I was already wondering a bit. I'll post it here in a new thread then

Comment: Why don't you download space engine and play with it. Universe sandbox 2 is excellent if you don't mind paying some money

Comment: @slobodan.blazeski thank you, I haven't heard of space engine before. I just tested it. How different is from Celestia when it comes to creating own solar systems? I haven't touched these possibilities with Celestia yet

Comment: @Polarelch Haven't tried Celestia, so I can't be of any help.  I could only say that  Universe sandbox 2 is great.

Comment: @slobodan.blazeski , thank you so so much for encouringing me to get Universe Sandbox 2, I was sceptical when I only saw "collision porn" before when I checked it out, but thank god (or you) that I actually got it. I now have a more or less stable solar system with my planet and moons (rearranged them) all set up. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is really just [basic trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_diameter).

```
radius / distance = tan(angle / 2)
```

or rearanged for diameter:

```
diameter = distance * tan(angle / 2) * 2
```

For example: When you want your moon 1 to fill 0.5° of the sky (about as large as our moon), it needs to have a diameter of `19110km * tan(0.5 / 2) * 2 =` 166 km.

Comment: i have the impression that the question also asks for the actual diameter of the moon.

Comment: @Burki I think that's what this method provides.

Comment: you need either the real diameter or the apparent size. I understood the question so that it asks how big a moon has to be to match the information provided for distance and orbital period.

Comment: @Burki The orbital period is derived from distance and gravity. The size of an object doesn't matter for calculating its orbit.

Comment: Thanks, Philipp's reply is exactly what I was looking for. So the moon can have basically any reasonable size no matter the orbit and distance?

Comment: Hmmm... i would have expected that there should be an upper and a lower limit for the density. We would not want the moon to be a star, and we would not want it to be pulled apart by the gravitational pull of the planet. But i guess that still leaves a wide enough range for it to be "any sensible size".

Comment: @Polarelch With just one moon, there is a point where the moon's own gravity becomes non-negligible and you start getting a binary planet. And when you go even bigger, the relation which one is the planet and which one is the moon reverses. Also, there is the roche limit, which you say you are already aware of in the question. When you have multiple moons, you need to be careful that they don't start to influence each other's orbits, which leads to chaotic and unstable systems. [Orbital resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_resonance) can help to stabilize multiple large moons.

Comment: @Philipp thank you very much, I have reorganized and rescaled my large moons so that they are in an 1-2-4 resonance now. The small mars-moon-like moon should be fine as it is though, shouldn't it? It's not that important though, I think my people can live without that flying rock.

Comment: [Worldbuilding has $\LaTeX$ enabled.](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/607/627) Please use it.

Comment: @HDE226868 I'm sorry, but I am allergic to latex.